# C# OleDbDataReader returns no records but manual sql returns records

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have the following:

```
try
            {
                string u = "select count(*) from my_table";
                OleDbCommand runu = new OleDbCommand(u, connection);
                OleDbDataReader readu = runu.ExecuteReader();
                if (readu.HasRows)
                {
                    while (readu.Read())
                    {
                        exists = readu[0].ToString();
                    }
                    readu.Dispose();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception g)
            {
                OraLog.log(g.ToString());
            }
```

If I grab the select statement and run it through SQLDeveloper I get records back.

I have used this same block of code on other things and it works fine but this time...it for some reason isn't returning any records.

I have disconnected from SQLDeveloper reconnected and made sure that the data is committed.

I dont get any exceptions either, I just get back no results.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your connection open? Any exception? What exception is being logged? Did you debug the code ?

Comment: No Exception I call the connection.Open() I have it wrapped in a try catch but no exception not entirely sure what the deal is....if I grab the command and just copy paste into sqldev it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed was a lack of `connection.Open();`, then I noticed that you were running this as an `Execute.Reader()` when you were only retrieving a single value.

I did a little rewrite, adding the `int RowCount` prior to the try, adding in the `connection.Open()` and then setting its value from an `ExecuteScalar()` command, which will just return the first value from a query. I also moved the `connection.Close()` into a `finally` block.

I didn't use your `exist` as is because it seemed like this should be a `bool` as opposed to a string, You can add on whatever supporting code to do what you want with the RowCount value.

```
int RowCount;
try {
    connection.Open();
    string u = "select count(*) from my_table";
    OleDbCommand runu = new OleDbCommand(u, connection);
    RowCount = (int)runu.ExecuteScalar();
}
catch (Exception g) { /* unchanged */ }
finally {  connection.Close(); }
```

RowCount will equal *null* if the command fails, and an integer of 0+ for however many rows are in the table.

Comment: I will try this, and post results

Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you still have problems, or mark it as answered if it works for you.

Comment: Marking it as the answer it helped me figure out that it was actually not committed.....I imported data into the db and never ran a commit.

Thanks for the help